# Bookmarking PDF in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, google-chrome-extension

Lately I've been reading a lot of PDF books using Google Chrome. To go to a particular page, you can simply append #page=23 to the url (as in file:///C:/my_book.pdf#page=23). This is a nice and easy way to bookmark your current page number to continue reading the book later.

**My question:**

What's a way to find out what page you're currently in within the book?

OR

What's a Chrome plugin that bookmarks PDF files within your file system?

I've tried a few extensions, but they don't work unless the book is in a server (as in http:// localhost/my_book.pdf), which is not desired in my case.

Thanks!

Comment: `#page=x` doesn't work for me in Chrome *v89*.

Comment: @Roi I'm on Chrome v89, and it works for me just fine. You might have to do Ctrl+R. It also works on Microsoft Edge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Chrome version 31+ the page number is displayed by the scroll bar if you scroll at all. I'm not sure when (what version) this feature was added.

Comment: This was sure added in a previous version, as I have notice it for some time now, but I am not sure at what version exactly.

Comment: I know. Come to think of it, I'm having a hard time remembering Chrome not having this feature, but obviously the feature wasn't always there...

Comment: The page number of also displayed on a black bar that slides in when you move mouse over the page. I wish, however, I could bookmark a specific scroll location and current zoom level and have Chrome do this automatically (it's find if it needs to be enabled once) and return to the last location for all PDF documents.

Comment: But is there a way to update the hash `#page=x` automatically?

Answer (score 1):

There's a chrome extension called **"PDF Bookmark"** it is free and works in my case.
Here's the [link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pdf-bookmark/mcalpfgelkfeonobdckkjgkgmcmjamgb/related) for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

Does it automatically update the hash tag to the page number?

If so, you could use `document.location.hash` as follows:

```
currentPage = document.location.hash.split("="); currentPage = currentPage[1];
```

Comment: It doesn't update the page number. If you open a PDF in Chrome, you can scroll through the pages, or press the right/left keys to advance a page at a time. The URL never actually changes. The way I've been bookmarking is by counting the pages by hand, then manually adding the hash tag.

Comment: Ah I see. I can't see a way to make this work myself - it just builds a HTML page and embeds it from the external plugin:

<html><body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="background-color: rgb(38,38,38)"><embed width="100%" height="100%" name="plugin" src="test.pdf" type="application/pdf"></body></html>

It looks like Chrome embeds FoxitReaders software for its built in PDF viewer - so you might be able to look through their SDK for something?

http://googlesystem.blogspot.com.au/2010/08/google-chromes-pdf-plugin-uses-foxit.html

Answer (score -2):

not very user friendly but you can append `document.documentElement.scrollTop` property value to the url 
on the console

```
> document.documentElement.scrollTop
<- 4000
```

bookmark as "file://path/to/pdf.pdf#4000"
and then when you reopen it use that value to set the same property

```
document.documentElement.scrollTop = 4000
```

a simple user script should be able to do this...